# Can i inject bean depend on package?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can i inject bean depend on package ? package A inject AImpl, pakage B inject BImpl. I can't using qualifier because class injected interface is library.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not! But you can use `@Qualifier` to pick the specific type of `bean` you desire. Eg:

```
@Bean("hi") String h1() {return "hi";}
@Bean("hello") String h2() {return "hello";}

@Bean ApplicationRunner runner(@Qualifier("hi") String str) {
    return args -> {
        System.out.println(str);
    };
}
```